# setup consistent tunnel between two hosts wirh dynamic IPs

Tags: shell-script, ssh-tunneling, autossh

I would like to setup a constant ssh tunnel between two hosts. Now it becomes tricky as both hosts may change their IPs (not at the same time though). My idea to overcome this is to have two reverse tunnels established from each host using `autoissh` (`A->B` & `B->A`) my mind experiment:

and as soon as `A` changes its IP:

`B` will still be able to access `A` because the reverse tunnel from `A->B`  is still alive, a script on `B` would realize that the IP of `A` has changed (by polling [ipchicken.com](https://ipchicken.com/) e.g.) and the reverse tunnel from `B->A` has to be re-established.

This would also work the other way around....is this right? Is there a better solution to achieve this, other than using `bash` and `autossh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be to use `autossh` with a [dynamic DNS service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) for the machines with changing IP addresses.

You could setup the tunnel using the FQDN and use client software like [ddclient](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/wiki/Home/) that handles the automatic changing of IP to domain name.

Comment: Yes, I've used the dyn IP service fromn `http://noIP.com` but because your IP doesn't change on a regular basis, you have to manually reconfirm every two weeks or so (in the free account anyways), which gets really annoying. I'm open though to try an alternative service, too!

Comment: I now decided to sign up with `https://www.cloudns.net/` - i'll give that a try but I'll still want to explore the option described in my original post on top. I'll accept your answer anyways as the post didn't really get much attention anyways.. Thanks!